# Use old PR viewer in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, version-control, webstorm

I like a lot of the changes in the latest update to WebStorm, but PLEASE tell me there's a way to switch back to viewing GitHub reviews one file at a time!

Comment: You can disable this in ide Registry, press double-shift and type registry

Registries are:
**gitlab.enable.combined.diff** - for gitlab
**github.enable.combined.diff** - for github
**enable.combined.diff** - for git log

Comment: @DinoLetic thank you!!! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this in ide Registry, press double-shift and type registry Registries are: gitlab.enable.combined.diff - for gitlab github.enable.combined.diff - for github enable.combined.diff - for git log